# Why should we use spring's hibernate?

Tags: spring, hibernate

I am currently using Spring 2 + Hibernate 3.

Question 1: What is the good reason to use hibernate framework within Spring's IoC?

Question 2: Why not separate hibernate framework from Spring's IoC framework?

Question 3: For those who experienced using hibernate in Spring 3, is there any pain? (I noted that Spring 3 has much lesser configuration)

The reason why I ask this question is that I think using hibernate within Spring's IoC caused hibernate to be tightly coupled with Spring and caused the configuration file to be much complicated. Please enlighten me.

Comment: Hope you had a look at benefits listed here: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/orm.html

Comment: Just don't use `HibernateTemplate`.

Comment: Hi Wand Maker, I do understand what the documentation is trying to say. But in terms of practical application, is it better to implement hibernate framework apart from Spring IoC implementation?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Wand Maker.

I have found the answer I need in the link provided:  http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/orm.html at the 13.3 Hibernate portion which explains the different ways to implement DAO using spring hibernate.